# C++ - two times DrawText()

Tags: c++, winapi, drawtext

I'm currently experiencing an error with my program.
My program has two rectangles, each of them surrounded by a groupbox.
Currently I'm trying two place text in each of them.
I've already got text in the first rectangle - fine (with `DrawText()`).
If I'm trying to display text in the second rectangle (also with `DrawText()`), the text is not displaying.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
SelectObject(hdc, font);
DrawText(hdc, lpcwstr, wcslen(lpcwstr), &rect, DT_LEFT);
DrawText(hdc, lpcwstr, wcslen(lpcwstr), &rect_2, DT_LEFT);
EndPaint(FindWindow(NULL, L"Statistik (seit dem 01.01.2015)"), &ps);
```

Unfortunately I have no idea why the text is not displaying as expected.
Does anybody of you have a suggestion why this doesn't work?

Comment: Check your error returns. Also why are you calling `FindWindow()` in your `EndPaint()`? That's not guaranteed to return the same window you're thinking of (if any window)... and you know the `hwnd` you passed to `BeginPaint()`; just use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SOLUTION]**
I was able to figure out what the problem was.
Not visible in the snippet, I posted initially, but the coordinates I set for the rectangles, were wrong.
Sadly I were not aware that all values are coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between the two calls is the `RECT` that you pass. The obvious conclusion is that you initialised one of the rectangles incorrectly.

You should restore the original font before calling `EndPaint`. And the call to `FindWindow` should be removed. Pass `hwnd`. Finally, your code performs no error checking at all. That's always imprudent.